# Is $U_1 = \{ f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x^2) = f(x)^2 \text{ for all } x \in\mathbb{R}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove or disprove the following statements:

1. $U_1 = \{ f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x^2) = f(x)^2 \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.
2. $U_4 = \{([i]_3,[j ]_3) \ | \ [i]_3 + [2]_3 \cdot [j]_3 = 0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^2_3$

So I've done similar tasks just now. I could find solution but only after someone told me whether they're a subspace or not. For most of them I used the definition (additive neutral element, closed under addition and multiplication).
Now I've picked out two tasks here that I'd love to see a step-by-step explanation of how to solve them.

Comment: *"I could find solution but only after someone told me whether they're a subspace or not"* Then assume someone tells you it is not, find a counterexample. And if you fail, assume he tells you it is, then prove it. More seriously, what does it mean for a subset to be a subspace? What are the conditions?

Comment: Checking that a subset is closed under addition, scalar multiplication and contains the additive identity is not a definition but a result that tells us that the subset in question is a subspace.

Comment: @Seeker Well, it's a definition in my book. Literally.

Comment: @Seeker It's the definition in my two texts, as well. To the OP: Did you try checking if $f(x^2)+g(x^2)$ equals $(f(x)+g(x))^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin In the book I am reading, a subset of a vector space was defined to be a subspace if it was also a vector space with respect to the same addition and scalar multiplication as the parent space. Then it was proven that if that subset satisfies those three conditions, then it is a subspace.

Comment: @Seeker I have at least one example of defining the other way around. But it really doesn't matter, they are equivalent. No need to make a fuss about this.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I agree.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've tried disproving the scalar multiplication with 2- i think that worked out fine with function $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $x \mapsto x$

Comment: Sure. That already appears in the answers you got. There are usually (but not always) several things that fail when you try to check that a non-subspace is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no universal, formal step-by-step process for these kinds of problems. However, here's my thought process in solving these, which you might find helpful.

The set $U_1$: the first thing I notice is that something is "squared", which is a non-linear operation, so probably the set is not a linear subspace. The easiest way to do that is to show that the set does not contain $0$, but in this case $0 \in U_1$. The next thing to try is to find a "vector" $f$ such that $f \in U_1$ but for some scalar $c \in \Bbb R$, $cf \notin U_1$. The simplest elements of ${\Bbb R}^{\Bbb R}$ to think about are constant functions. If $f(x) = k$ (for all $x \in \Bbb R$), then $f \in U_1$ if and only if $k = k^2$, which is to say $k \in \{0,1\}$.

So, we have a simple counterexample: setting $k=1$ gives us the element $f(x) = 1$, which is an element of $U_1$. However, taking $c = 2$, we find that the function $g = c\cdot f$ (given by $g(x) = 2$) is not an element of $U_1$.

The set $U_4$: the equation defining the set is a linear equation. Indeed, $U_4$ is the solution set to the homogeneous equation $Ax = 0$ with
$$
A = \pmatrix{[1]_3 & [2]_3}, \quad x \in \Bbb Z_3^2.
$$
In other words, $U_4$ is the nullspace of $A$. It follows that $U_4$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

The first is not a subspace. It's not closed under scalar multiplication, since in general $cf(x^2) \neq [cf(x)]^2=c^2 f(x)^2$. For a specific example, $f(x)=x$ lies in $U_1$ but $2f$ does not.

Here's a general fact that's useful for the second example: Let $X,Y$ be vector spaces over the same field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $T:X\to Y$ be linear (that is, $T(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha T(x)+\beta T(y)$) for all $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{F}$ and $x,y\in X$. Then $\ker(T):=\{x\in X:T(x)=0_Y\}$ is a subspace of $X$. This is because $T(0_X)=T(0_\mathbb{F}\cdot 0_X)=0_\mathbb{F}T(0_X)=0_Y$, so $0_X\in \ker(T)$, and if $x,y\in \ker(T)$, then for any $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{F}$, $$T(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha T(x)+\beta T(y)=\alpha\cdot 0_Y+\beta\cdot 0_Y=0_Y,$$ so $\alpha x+\beta y\in \ker(T)$. As stated in the comments, this is good enough to show that $\ker(T)$ is a subspace of $X$.

Your second example is the kernel of $T(x,y)=x+2y$ from $X=\mathbb{Z}^2_3$ to $Y=\mathbb{Z}_3$ over the field $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z}_3$.